# Nodejs and VS Code debugging. Breakpoints are set but not bound

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

SO I'm using VS Code 1.40.2 (on macOS) and trying to debug my server side application. Launch config is

```
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach by Process ID",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        "skipFiles": [
          "<node_internals>/**"
        ]
```

I'm running the app in terminal with either `node --inspect app.js` or `npm start`

Application is running, debugger is attached but all breakpoints are greyed out and show Breakpoint is set but not yet bound.

None of the solutions I've found after hours of searching seem to work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `node --inspect-brk app.js`?

Comment: @Saeed yes I've tried it. No luck.